# Is there a conventional way to document Jest/Puppeteer test suites?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

**Summary of problem:** I'm writing several test suites using Jest and Puppeteer to automate end-to-end testing of my Angular JS app. I'm big on documentation, as it is important to help future developers get up to speed more quickly. Unfortunately, **I don't know of a conventional/widely accepted method for documenting test suites written with Jest**. I've already written an extensive README that explains the tools we're using, how my team configured Jest/Puppeteer, and how to get started writing tests. What I'm specifically wondering about is how to document WITHIN each test suite, or if it is even necessary to spend time doing that (I'm leaning towards *yes, it is **definitely** worth spending time doing that* on the latter question).

**Here's some sample code that I'd like to document:**

```
// index.spec.js
// Insert comment here describing test file (aka test suite)
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Insert comment here describing test suite
    describe('load startpage', async () => {
        // Insert comment here describing test
        test('page loads', async () => {
          await page.goto('https://my-site.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
        });
    });
    // Insert comment here describing test suite
    describe('complete form', async () => {
        // Insert comment here describing test
        test('populate form', async () => {
            let formSelector = 'form[name="form1"]';
            await page.waitForSelector(formSelector, {timeout: 3000}); 
            await page.waitForSelector(formSelector+' input', {timeout: 3000});
            await page.click(formSelector+' input');
            await page.keyboard.type('Hello World');
            let submitButtonSelector = 'form[name="form1"] button[type="submit"]';
            await page.click(submitButtonSelector);
        });
        // Insert comment here describing test
        test('submit form', async() => {
            let submitButtonSelector = 'form[name="form1"] button[type="submit"]';
            await page.waitForSelector(submitButtonSelector, {timeout: 3000}); 
            await page.click(submitButtonSelector);
        });
    });
    await browser.close();
})();
```

**What I've already tried:**
I've researched a little about the conventional method for documenting Javascript via [JSDoc](https://devdocs.io/jsdoc/), but I don't really think this applies here because I'm using the Jest and Puppeteer Apis, which I assume are wrappers for native Javascript functions.

**Question:** Do any of you Jest/Puppeteer hackers know of the proper way to document tests? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, for one thing you can make the `describe` and `test` strings more verbose and narrative. For instance, `describe('completing the hello world form', ... test('I can populate the form and submit it',...); test('I can submit the form without populating it', ...));`. Then, if a test fails, people know exactly what failed rather than some cryptic "complete form submit form" string. But that's my opinion, and opinion questions are generally not welcome on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for the response. I will definitely take your advice and make my `describe` and `test` descriptors more verbose. I'm sorry that you think my question is an opinion question. I certainly didn't intend for it to be. I understand that documentation conventions can vary based on the preferences of a single developer or team. There are some universal standards, however, like writing README's. I was only curious to see if there were any standards/conventions out there that exist for e2e test documentation, that's all. Anyways, thanks again for your response :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try and tailor this response to not sound completely opinionated.

Yes, documentation is essential, but too much of it doesn't play well either.

In the case of tests, be it unit/integration/e2e, frameworks already give you all the constructs you'll ever need to specify/document your tests. To my knowledge, there aren't any other conventions to document test suites.

The describe/it/test/etc blocks should be thought of as documentation and they should guide any developer through the intentions of whoever wrote the test.

In rare cases, any other essential commentary can be done inline.

The beauty of tests is that when their specification is well written, it reads like a book when run. And yes, describing your tests in small phrases is hard, just like naming a variable. Takes practice but it's doable.

Any documentation needed besides that you already covered in your README.

Apart from having good test specifications, you'll gain much more value in ensuring the tests are written with consistency instead of trying to explain what's going on in detail in each test, let the code do that.